Headless Raspberry Pi Zero: Password not working when properly imaged on Raspberry Pi Imager
When SSH'ing into my Pi (via IP address) from my work computer (PC), I normally see this at the password prompt:

pi@123.456.78.901's password:

In this scenario, I can log in successfully.
However, when I try the same thing (for the same Pi) from my laptop (PC), I see this:

abcde/wyatt@123.456.78.901's password:

...which results in this after password entry:

Permission denied, please try again.

I have tried:

Re-imaging the micro SD card with Raspberry Pi Imager
Reformatting the card with SD Card Formatter then re-imaging with Raspberry Imager
A different micro SD card (both San Disk) with same results

Any thoughts?

You’re not using the same username. Specify the username when you connect to the remote system

This one stumped me! Thanks, it worked!


However, when I try the same thing (for the same Pi) from my laptop (PC), I see this:

abcde/wyatt@123.456.78.901's password:


You are using two different usernames to connect to the 123.456.78.901 machine. Using the following syntax instead:
ssh pi@123.456.78.901

Should work on both machines. This way you are connecting to a username that exists in the remote system instead of only existing on the local machine.
